# How to format the jQuery UI Progress Bar

Tags: jquery-ui, progress-bar

I'm using the default [jQuery Progress Bar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) and I can't seem to figure out a couple of things:

Firstly, I've nested it in an AP div tag so that it fits perfectly with a certain area on my page, which is fine but the problem is that the percentage overlay comes up a bit short in that it doesn't cover the entire area of the bar, it doesn't reach the bottom border.

Secondly (not that much of a problem, merely a curiosity) how would I go about changing the colour of the progress bar?

Comment: for the page or the progress bar?

Comment: that which you have problems with

Comment: I provided the example in my initial post... the source code for the Default Functionality of the Progress bar is my exact code except that i've made the jquery-ui.css file local.

Comment: http://fts.davidfattore.com/players/player_profiles.php?id=1

That is the page I have it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `default.css` file:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index:3;
}
```

`box-sizing` applies to the progressbar value, so fix it like adding to CSS:

```
.ui-progressbar-value {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;

        /* This way you can change the progress color */
        background-color: #000000 !important; 
}
```